# Android - Fragment findViewById() always null?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

Yes, I realize there are questions VERY similar to this one, but unlike the others, my `onCreateView()` method inflates the view for the fragment. When I don't use `findViewById()`, everything inflates and my app works as expected (except for the functionality for the views I want to get in `findViewById()`.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater p_inflater, ViewGroup p_container, Bundle p_prev_state)
{
    return p_inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, p_container, false);
}
```

Whenever I want to access a ListView within my layout, I do this:

```
private ListView getListView()
{
    return (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.main_events);
}
```

but this is always null. Why? My `fragment_main.xml` looks like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="me.k.cal.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/main_events"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="@color/background_color" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[My full fragment code can be found here.](http://pastebin.com/adNMjaxi)

Comment: `findViewById` can be attached with a view..So in Fragment , you need to use it as `view.findViewById`

Comment: When exactly are you calling `getListView()` or a method that calls it, with regards to the fragment lifecycle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Below Code to inflate your view and get id of listview.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    View _view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    ListView _list= (ListView) _view.findViewById(R.id.main_events);
    return _view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and apologies for my slow response time. The `_list` view is still null when I run this... Is `onCreateView()` called in lieu of the ctor?

Comment: i think your layout is in activity xml and you are accessing it from fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,hope this helps

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
            false);

    ListView eventsList= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_events);

 return view;

}
```